# How can I get the an reference to an mat-option object in material auto complete component

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am trying to replace boostrap's combobox with material's autocomplete without refactoring much of the previous code;

This is what the html of the new material autocomplete looks like :

```
<input matInput placeholder="New room" aria-label="Newsroom Source" [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup" [formControl]="newsRoomCtrl" [value] = 'selectedNewsFeed.sourceName'>
<mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='onNewsRoomSelect($event.value)'   >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let newsroomsource of filteredNewsRoomSources | async"  [value]="newsroomsource" [attr.data-row]="newsroomsource">
      <span>{{ newsroomsource.sourceName }}</span> |
      <small>Type: {{ newsroomsource.sourceType }}</small>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

On '(optionSelected)' event I  call the function `onNewsRoomSelect(selectedNewsRoom: NewsRoomSource)` by passing the selected newsroomsource as an object using event.value

This works fine ,the problem  though is that the value of the input becomes an object in this case and NewsRoomSource object, and this is what I see in the input after the selection is made;

Selecting:
[image: Selecting]

After selection :
[image: After Selection]

Now I understand why this happens as I set [value] of the mat-input tag to an object i.e. newsroomsource,  but I don't know how else I can reference the selected object if I don't do this.

As you can see in the code I tried using data-attribute but wasn't sure how exactly I can use it in this case

Answer (score 0):

In this case `newsRoomCtrl` has the reference of the selected object try by printing this variable `console.log(newsRoomCtrl);`

Finally I think it is going to be like that, take a look to the object structure to be sure.

```
    <input matInput placeholder="New room" aria-label="Newsroom Source" [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup" 
[formControl]="newsRoomCtrl" [value] = 'newsRoomCtrl.value.sourceName'>
```

Comment: I am trying to get an reference to the selected newsRoomObject in the mat-autocomplete tag for the  (optionSelected) event 

And the way I doing it right now is by saying [value] = 'newsRoomCtrl.value' if i change this to newsRoomCtrl.value.sourceName then I loose the reference to the object in the mat-autocomplete tag